# Ajax cart not working in class

Tags: magento-1.9

I used ajax cart to the form. My problem is if  i use `id` ajax working fine but if i use `class` it won't work for ajax cart.

I have a marketplace if same product have more then one seller it shows that seller information as well as cart so that i used `class` if i used `id` then i try add product of second seller but first seller product only added to the cart. so that i used `class`

**Using id:**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form">

<button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"  class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>">
    <span>
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button><div>
    <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
    <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button></div>

</form>
```

My .js file

```
if(el.up('form#seller_addtocart_form')){
                    var url =   $('seller_addtocart_form').readAttribute('action');
                    var link = url.replace('checkout','ajaxcart').replace('wishlist/index','ajaxcart/wishlist').replace('https','http');                    
                    el.onclick = function(){
                        if(productAddToCartForm.submit){
                            var emajcForm = productAddToCartForm;
                            if (('undefined' != typeof productAddToCartFormOld) && productAddToCartFormOld)
                                emajcForm   =   productAddToCartFormOld;
                            if(emajcForm.validator && emajcForm.validator.validate()){
                                jQuery('#seller_addtocart_form').ajaxForm(options);
                                $('seller_addtocart_form').setAttribute("action", link);
                                jQuery('#seller_addtocart_form').submit();
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

**Using class**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="seller_addtocart_form" class="ma">

<button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"  class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>">
        <span>
        <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button><div>
        <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
        <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button></div>

    </form>
```

My .js file

```
if(el.up('form.ma')){
                var url =   $$('form.ma').readAttribute('action');
                var link = url.replace('checkout','ajaxcart').replace('wishlist/index','ajaxcart/wishlist').replace('https','http');                    
                el.onclick = function(){
                    if(productAddToCartForm.submit){
                        //alert('Hai');
                        var emajcForm = productAddToCartForm;
                        if (('undefined' != typeof productAddToCartFormOld) && productAddToCartFormOld)
                            emajcForm   =   productAddToCartFormOld;
                        if(emajcForm.validator && emajcForm.validator.validate()){
                            jQuery('.ma').ajaxForm(options);
                            $('ma').setAttribute("action", link);
                            jQuery('.ma').submit();
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

i checked in consolve, it shows

```
TypeError: $(...) is null
var url = $('ma').readAttribute('action');
```

i don't know what mistake i done.

Comment: did you try just swapping `$('ma').readAttribute('action')` with `$('.ma').readAttribute('action')` ? and you would probably need to change  `$('ma').setAttribute("action", link)` to `$('.ma').setAttribute("action", link)` as well

Comment: that also i tried it redirect to shopping cart page

Comment: is there is any way to submit a form on same page and product added to the cart

Answer (score 0):

As per as prototype js library, if you want to ***get form action  using class name then you need to  use $$() instead of  this $()***

**So please  change**

```
$('ma').readAttribute('action')
```

**to**

```
$$('form.ma').readAttribute('action')
```

In prototype ***$('ma')*** only work when  `ma is form id` not class name.

Comment: No it's redirect to shopping cart not ajax

Comment: have u check `$$('form.ma').readAttribute('action')` given action url?

Comment: ya i changed but not working check my updated question

Comment: showing maintenance  page

Comment: Oh sorry my server team restrict ip check my update js

Comment: is there is any way to submit a form on same page and product added to the cart

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple forms you can add `onsubmit` event for each form and can able do your stuff for particular submitted from.

That way you don't need to keep duplicate ids for each form content like you are doing for `id="seller_addtocart_form"`.

You can do something like

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">

<script>
    function validateForm(form){
        // you can do your all ajax stuff here..
        alert(form.readAttribute('action'));
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can i use same ajax function

Comment: yes you can do the same thing but there might be some modification require.

Comment: i used same thing but it won't work can you please tell me what modification i posted my js also here